# How can I modify the plot format of stcurve?

Tags: plot, stata, survival-analysis

My code is as follows:

```
    use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/uis.dta, clear
    stset time, failure(censor)
    streg , dist(weibull) 
    stcurve, hazard
```

I am looking for a way to personalize the format of output plot in `stcurve`. For instance, how can I change the light blue background color, labels, font size, and heading of the plot?

Comment: In my view too open. This is asking for a personal tutorial on a large fraction of Stata graphics!

Comment: Here is a tutorial http://data.princeton.edu/stata/graphics.html

Comment: @NickCox Sorry for the general question. I am new to Stata.

Comment: @timat Thanks for the tutorial. It was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first look in `help stcurve`: there is a link to `help twoway_options`
All is there.

For the font, see the Stata manual [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-2graphset.pdf).

Here an example for what you've asked:

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/uis.dta, clear
stset time, failure(censor)
streg , dist(weibull) 

graph set window fontface "Times New Roman"
#delimit ;
stcurve, hazard
title("new title")
graphregion(color(white) icolor(white))
plotregion(color(white) icolor(white))
ytitle( "Y title",size(3.5)) 
xtitle( "X title",size(3.5)) ;
#delimit cr
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it was really helpful